# Mysql workbench cannot connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Since I am on Ubuntu 15.10 (I was on 14.10 before) I can't connect to mysql with mysql-workbench, even if connection test is successful.
Is there a way to make the connection work?

[image]

[image]

I have forced the connection to TCP, but it still doesn't work.

```
mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1  
mysql -u root -p --protocol=TCP

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      55
Current database:   
Current user:       root@localhost
SSL:            Not in use
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server version:     5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
TCP port:       3306
Uptime:         9 min 38 sec
```

Comment: Looks like you might have a default schema defined, is that true? Can you connect without a default schema set?

Comment: Same problem without default schema. I added this default schema thinking it would help to solve the problem : )

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue? Even I am facing the exact same problem. Can you please post the solution if you have found? T

Comment: no solution for now. Strange thing I have installed same linux on another pc and it works. but on mine, it doesn't.

Comment: try downgrading mysql workbench.